# How to retrieve specific records from data table in access with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am stuck on this code, is there anyone of you who could help me. I have a table "TblParticipants" where I store all data about formation. Each participant  have a specific ID "ParticipantID" and they receive many lessons which have also a corresponding ID "LessonID". What I want to do is display in a form under unbounded text boxes all lessonID the participant have been attending. I don't want to store all matching record in a new table but I just want them to be displayed, not i a one textbox with separated comma but in different textboxes.

Here is the code:

```
   Private Sub Form_Current()
   Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset
   Dim Arr As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim MyQuery As String
        MyQuery = "select *" & "from [TblParticipants]" & "where [ParticipantID] ='" & Me.IDtxtBox.Value & "'"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(MyQuery)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    While rs.EOF = False
        For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
            Arr = rs.Fields("LessonID") 'The field where I want to extract all matching records
                                    'with my query and put each matching record in separate text boxes
        'MsgBox Arr   'This message returns one by one what I exactly want but I don't know how to put each of them in a separated text box (unbound records without creating a new table)
            Select Case i
                Case i = 0
                    txtbox1.Value = Arr 'first lessonID the participant have been attending
                Case i = 1
                    txtbox1.Value = Arr '2nd lessonID the participant have been attending
                Case i = 2
                    txtbox1.Value = Arr '3rd lessonID the participant have been attending
                Case i = 3
                    txtbox1.Value = Arr '4th lessonID the participant have been attending
                Case i = 4
                    txtbox1.Value = Arr '5th lessonID the participant have been attending
            End Select
            rs.MoveNext
        Next i
    Wend
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        db.Close
        Set db = Nothing
    ErrorHandler:
       MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & 
    Err.Description
    End sub
```

Comment: If you want to put Arr values to different textboxes, why you put them to the same txtbox1?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, the should be txtbox1 to txtboxn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 5 textboxes with names `txtbox1`..`txtbox5` and the query returns no more than 5 records, then you can try this:

```
 While rs.EOF = False
    For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
        Arr = rs.Fields("LessonID") 
        Me.Controls("txtbox" & i + 1).Value = Arr
        rs.MoveNext
    Next i
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly that I want is.